# Disable Android 'Instant' app module for a flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

I have an Android app with paid and free flavors, and have been working on including 'instant' capabilities. I *don't* want the 'Try now' button to appear for my paid version, so I'd like to disable the instant app module for my paid flavor. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you checked this SO post wherein it [disabled the building of feature modules for a flavor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785873/unable-to-build-feature-modules-in-a-multi-flavor-app)?  The major module of your instant app is the base component module. All other element modules must rely upon the base element module.

Comment: I'm not sure about flavors yet... but you should be able to disable the Try Now for your paid version by setting the Mobile Holdback to 100% (ie. block all users from accessing your instant app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to disable the module to prevent enabling instant experience for the paid app. If you never upload your APK/Bundle in the "Android Instant Apps" release section, it won't be enabled for the paid app.

Even if you do upload it, you can still press "Stop Serving" in Google Play "Android Instant Apps" section, or adjust country distribution for the instant app to 0 countries.